# Lose Vim Color with ftp

Tags: vim, ftp, rpgle

Recently I've been creating my custom color scheme on VIM for RPGLE language and it works fine when I open files from my computer, but when I try to edit a file via FTP it doesn't work anymore.
Do I need some special config to achieve this?

Comment: does `:set ft?` give you expected value?

Comment: You were right I fixed it by :set ft=rpgle. Thank you so much.